# Postgres could not receive data from client: Connection timed out

Tags: postgresql, timeout

Am a sql DBA, learning postgres..In postgres logs i often receive **"could not receive data from client: Connection timed out"** I do not have any other logs other than this

Am not sure how to troubleshoot? I check the application logs and DBs logs to compare the time but I could not notice any abnormalities.

can someone guide me how to trace this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A few possibilities:

- Your application closes connections without telling the PostgreSQL server it's doing so, by simply closing the network socket. It should send a `PQclose(conn)` if using `libpq`, or whatever equivalent your language/driver has.
- Network address translation timeouts on idle connections or other related network issues cause the TCP connections to break, so client and server lose communication with each other.
- A firewall on the client or server is blocking or disrupting connections after they're established (maybe malfunctioning IDS?)

Comment: _IDS_ meaning _Intrusion Detection_?

Answer (score 1):

iptables firewall may need a rule to be able to send out to the Postgres port you are connecting to:

```
iptables -L -n

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
```